# sparql-gremlin: how to achieve the same goal with java?

Tags: sparql, gremlin

I'm working on sparql-gremlin with Java program. Currently, I can do following query in gremlin command-line.

```
gremlin> g.sparql("SELECT ?name ?age WHERE { ?person v:name ?name . ?person v:age ?age } ORDER BY ASC(?age)")
==>[name:vadas,age:27]
==>[name:marko,age:29]
==>[name:josh,age:32]
==>[name:peter,age:35]
```

However, how can I do the same query with java? I tried following code, but received wrong result.

```
 Graph graph = TinkerFactory.createModern() ;
        try {
            SparqlTraversalSource g = graph.traversal(SparqlTraversalSource.class) ;
            GraphTraversal iter =  g.sparql("SELECT ?name ?age WHERE { ?person v:name ?name . ?person v:age ?age } ORDER BY ASC(?age)").V() ;
            
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Vertex v = (Vertex) iter.next();
                System.out.println(v.id().toString() + ", " + v.property("name") + ", " + v.label() + ", " + v.property("age")) ;
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Received result is:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.util.FileManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
1, vp[name->marko], person, vp[age->29]
2, vp[name->vadas], person, vp[age->27]
3, vp[name->lop], software, vp[empty]
4, vp[name->josh], person, vp[age->32]
5, vp[name->ripple], software, vp[empty]
6, vp[name->peter], person, vp[age->35]
1, vp[name->marko], person, vp[age->29]
2, vp[name->vadas], person, vp[age->27]
3, vp[name->lop], software, vp[empty]
4, vp[name->josh], person, vp[age->32]
5, vp[name->ripple], software, vp[empty]
6, vp[name->peter], person, vp[age->35]
1, vp[name->marko], person, vp[age->29]
2, vp[name->vadas], person, vp[age->27]
3, vp[name->lop], software, vp[empty]
4, vp[name->josh], person, vp[age->32]
5, vp[name->ripple], software, vp[empty]
6, vp[name->peter], person, vp[age->35]
1, vp[name->marko], person, vp[age->29]
2, vp[name->vadas], person, vp[age->27]
3, vp[name->lop], software, vp[empty]
4, vp[name->josh], person, vp[age->32]
5, vp[name->ripple], software, vp[empty]
6, vp[name->peter], person, vp[age->35]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by myself. I should call fill() after sparql() invocation.